Opening a thumb in image-dired opens a new thumb display buffer each time
Hitting image-dired-display-this (bound to key RET) and image-dired-display-next (bound to key ') in the image-dired-thumbnail buffer opens/duplicates another image-dired-thumbnail buffer each time.
Any ideas where to start investigating the cause of this issue?
 %* *image-dired*                                              30 image-dired-thumbnail 
 %* *image-dired*                                              30 image-dired-thumbnail 
 %* *image-dired*                                              30 image-dired-thumbnail 
 %* Pictures                                            423126 Dired by name    ~/Pictures/
    *image-dired-display-image*                           2330135 image-dired-image-display ~/Pictures/foo.jpg

Environment:
- OS: gnu/linux
- Emacs: 29.2
- Spacemacs: 0.999.0
- Spacemacs branch: develop (rev. ca10effc9)
- Graphic display: t
- Running in daemon: t
- Distribution: spacemacs
- Editing style: vim
- Completion: helm


I don't understand the description:are you seeing multiple buffers? What are their names? What does C-x C-b says about those buffers? What exactly are you seeing?

I'm not sure what to do: can you please explain exactly what you are doing? When I do M-x image-dired in a directory that contains a bunch of images, I get a sentinel error, but I only get a single *image-dired* buffer in C-x C-b. My setup is possibly corrupt, but I cannot reproduce what (I think) you report as the problem.

I can't reproduce the problem (emacs 30.0.50).  Each RET reuses the same *image-dired-display-image* buffer, there's still a single *image-dired* buffer.
